# Given a list of integers how do I check if it is possible to get 2 sublists of equal sum?

Tags: python, list

Given a single parameter (list of integers), return True if it's possible to get 2 sublists of equal sum, return False if it's not.

What I had initially was to initialize the 2 sublists first and start appending the integers from the sorted list into the sublist which has the smaller total sum.

```
def split_ls(arr):
    arr.sort()
    a = []
    b = []
    while arr:
        push = arr.pop()
        if sum(a) == sum(b) or push == 0:
            a.append(push)
        elif sum(a) > sum(b):
            if push < 0:
                a.append(push)
            else:
                b.append(push)
        else:
            if push < 0:
                b.append(push)
            else:
                a.append(push)

    if sum(a) == sum(b):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This would work for some test cases but not for all like...
arr = [7, -3, 6, 1, 10, -4, 2, 2, 6, 7, -3, 2, 4, 0, 7, 6, -2, 10, -4, 10]

Comment: An important point is missing in your question: can you reorder the items, or do you just need to find a which point to split your list in two? In the first case, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem

Comment: My bad, yes you can re-order the items. We just need to check if there is a way to split the given list into 2 sublists of equal sum. Also, an item can be in either sublists but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is NP-hard.

A rather 'brute' way to to it is to try all possible combinations of 1, 2... up to half the number of values in the list to find one that adds to half the total sum.

It might be good to estimate the number of such combinations before trying to run the code. We need to test at most half the number of subsets of your list of length n, so 2^n / 2 = 2^(n-1).

For your list of 20 values, that would be 2^19 = 524288, which can still be done in reasonable time.

So, we can try combinations generated using `itertools.combinations` until we find one with half the sum, then build the other half list by removing the values we found from the original list:

```
from itertools import combinations 


def find_half_sum(arr):
    half_sum = sum(arr)/2

    for comb_size in range(1, len(arr)//2 + 1):
        for comb in combinations(arr, comb_size):
            if sum(comb) == half_sum:
                second = arr[:]
                for v in first:
                    second.remove(v)
                return(first, second)
            
    raise ValueError("Can't split this array in equal sums")
    
arr = [7, -3, 6, 1, 10, -4, 2, 2, 6, 7, -3, 2, 4, 0, 7, 6, -2, 10, -4, 10]
first, second = find_half_sum(arr)
    
print(first, sum(first))
print(second, sum(second))

#(6, 10, 6, 10) 32
#[7, -3, 1, -4, 2, 2, 7, -3, 2, 4, 0, 7, 6, -2, -4, 10] 32
```

Comment: I had supposed that the list was to be split in two lists of equal length and equal sum (which had a solution in the example case). This constraint wasn't part of the question, so now we look for sublists of any length.